# Apache HTTP Server Load Balancer-File does not exist exception

Tags: apache, websphere, load-balancing

I am using single Apache HTTP Server (2.2.23) as a Load Balancer with two IBM Websphere application server nodes (other machines). I have deployed the simple text based helloWorld application and it works fine with load balancer. But When I deploy the real application that contains images, css files, java script files. It loads the page without images and show me simple text and gives me the following Exception on error_logs and similar kind of exceptions:

> [error] [client `192.217.71.77`] File does not exist: /usr/local/apache2/htdocs/application, referer:
>   `http://192.168.141.17/application/faces/test.jsp`

Interestingly, when I access the application without load balancer, it also works fine.

Here are the load balancer settings

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName test.com:80
<Proxy balancer://mybalancer>
BalancerMember `http://192.168.141.13:9081` route=1
BalancerMember `http://192.168.141.13:9082` route=2
Order allow,deny
Allow from all
</Proxy>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteLog "/usr/local/apache2/logs/rewrite.log"
RewriteLogLevel 5
ProxyPass /application/faces/test.jsp balancer://mybalancer/application/faces/test.jsp
ProxyPassReverse /application/faces/test.jsp 
balancer://mybalancer/application/faces/test.jsp
</VirtualHost>
```

I access the application from my machine to the load balancers machine using the following URL : `http://192.168.141.17/application/faces/test.jsp`

Is there any module/configuration I am missing that stop the Apache to load images on browser?   Please advise.

Answer (score 0):

You're only Proxying test.jsp by itself, not the entire context root of the application.  You need to ProxyPass a pattern that includes the resources that triggered the 404 (old Apache doesn't include it in the error log entry properly)